# What content is available from Chrome browser when sharing to other app?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

After sharing from chrome to my app, I am able to fetch the website link by calling getStringExtra on the intent object. Like this,

```
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

What are the other content from the website that can be obtained in my app? Like getting the page title, etc.

Comment: You can certainly check for any of the extras [documented for `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). Beyond that, I do not know if they document what else Chrome might include. You could always add in some code to examine all the extras that you get on that `Intent`, to see what the current version of Chrome is doing. Also, bear in mind that other apps might share with your app, and they may or may not support the same undocumented extras.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have seen Pocket app getting most of the website content. Trying to figure out if they load the site themselves or pull that from the intent. 
Examining all the extras with checks for NPE is a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Just get the `Bundle` of extras and iterate over the keys to see what's in there.